# Error calling class method from extended Electron class

Tags: javascript, electron, extends, derived-class, method-call

First of all, I'm a newbie on javascript and Electron.
This is a code snippet to replicate a concept coming from a basic Javascrip/Electron tutorial on YouTube, that for some reason is not working for me.

- Define a base class "base"
- Define a class called "derived" that extends "base"
- In derived constructor, call super() and then call the derived class method this.showSomething()

Everything works as expected. Now, define a derived class by extending Tray (Electron class) and do the same things:

- Define a class called "derivedFromTray" that extends "Tray"
- In derived constructor, call super() and then call the derived class method this.showSomething()
  This leads to an error: **this.ShowSomething is not a function**

Am I missing something in the script? Why this happens?

**NOTE 1: I'm not interested in alternative coding solutions to call the extended class methods**, unless there is a clear indication that, by design, deriving Electron classes breaks the coding solution used in this snippet.

You can find the tutorial here: [How To Code - Electron JS Tutorial #46](https://youtu.be/4mDj5xBcoP0?t=189)

Node version: 15.8.0 - Electron version: 11.2.3

Code to replicate the issue:

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const {app, Tray} = electron;

class base{
    constructor(path){
        this.internalPath = path        
    }
    
}

class derived extends base {
    constructor(path) {
        super(path)
        this.showSomething();
    }
    showSomething() 
    {    
        console.log(`internal Path: ${this.internalPath}`);
    }
}

class derivedFromTray extends Tray {
    constructor(iconPath) {
        super(iconPath)
        this.showSomething() // ERROR: this.showSomething is not a function
    }
    showSomething() 
    {    
        console.log('Log from derivedFromTray.showSomething');
    }    
}

app.on('ready', ()=>{
    // WARNING: specify a valid image path or the example
    // will not work!
    const paramPath = path.join(__dirname, "app_tray_icon.png")
    const workingDerived = new derived(paramPath)
    const notWorkingDerived = new derivedFromTray(paramPath)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unless there is a clear indication that, by design, deriving Electron classes breaks the coding solution used in this snippet.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/25721

> we do not support extending built in classes in Electron

Built in classes in Electron are not plain javscript object and do not support all js behaviors like extending class.

Comment: Ok, this is what I call a "clear indication"... Thank you OJ Kwon!